# PBS stack size keeps constant

Tags: stack, pbs

I am trying to change the stack size on computing nodes, but no success so far.

I edited `limits.pbs_mom`, then restarted `pbs_mom`, but doesn't work.

Also edited `pbs`, then restarted `pbs`, still doesn't work.

used:

```
ulimit -H -s unlimited
ulimit -S -s unlimited
```

and `ulimit -a` looks fine.

Can anyone help me with it? Thank you very much in advance.